# Как на кнопках, кроме иконки можно добавить текст?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте!

Каким образом на кнопках https://tech.yandex.ru/share/, кроме иконки можно добавить текст? Напрмиер "Поделиться ВКонтакте", "Рассказать в Фейсбуке" и тп?

Comment: Теоретически можно яваскриптом на странице по именам классов каждой иконки найти элемент и дописать нужный текст. В документации яндекса нет такой информации, может плохо искал конечно...

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пришло на ум

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("ya-share2__item_service_collections");
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName("ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte");
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName("ya-share2__item_service_facebook");
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("ya-share2__item_service_odnoklassniki");
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("ya-share2__item_service_moimir");
    var aa = document.createElement("span");
    aa.innerText="Текст";
    a[0].appendChild(aa);
    var bb = document.createElement("span");
    bb.innerText="Текст";
    b[0].appendChild(bb);
    var cc = document.createElement("span");
    cc.innerText="Текст";
    c[0].appendChild(cc);
    var dd = document.createElement("span");
    dd.innerText="Текст";
    d[0].appendChild(dd);
    var ee = document.createElement("span");
    ee.innerText="Текст";
    e[0].appendChild(ee);
}, 2000);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `setTimeout` тут зачем, чет не понимаю?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, чисто для примера, можно заменить на событие onload объекта window.

Comment: а событие зачем?)

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, дабы избежать ситуации, когда скрипт выполнился, а элементы на странице еще не отстроились по причине не загруженных скриптов. Асинхронность и все такое типа...

Comment: понял. согласен)